# How to handle Caching and Revalidation in NextJS app deployed on Vercel

Tags: deployment, vercel, next.js13

I created an application on Nextjs and hosted it on Vercel. Now i discovered that if user on my app update their profile or the admin update the service on the page they update does not reflect until i redeploy to github.

I have tried to update my environment variables, but the problem persists

Comment: Refer this docs https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#revalidating-1